# Properly evaluating double integral in python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute a definite double integral using scipy. The integrand is a bit complicated, as it contains some probability distributions to give weight to how likely is each value of x and y (like a mixture model). The following code evaluated to a negative number, but it should be bound by [0,1]. Additionally, it took about half an hour to compute.

I have two questions.

1) Is there a better way to calculate this integral?

2) Where is this negative value coming from? The big question for me is how to speed the calculation up, as I can find the bug in my code that's leading to the negative later on my own.

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
import itertools

p= [list whose entries are each different stats.beta(a,b) distributions]

def integrand(x,y):
        delta=x-y
        marg=0
        for distA,distB in itertools.permutations(p,2):
                first=distA.pdf(x)
                second=distB.pdf(y)
                weight1=0
                weight2=0
                for distC in p:
                        if distC == distA:
                                continue
                        w1=distC.cdf(x)-distC.cdf(y)
                        if weight1 == 0:
                                weight1=w1
                        else:
                                weight1=weight1*w1
                marg+=(first*weight1*second)
        I=delta*marg
        return I

expect=dblquad(integrand,0,1,lambda x: 0, lambda x: x)
```

This is asking essentially what for the expected value of the maximal distance between two points is in a vector of distributions. The limits of integration are y ∊ [0,x] and x ∊ [0,1]. This gave me about -.49, with an estimated error of the integral on the order of 10e-10, so it shouldn't be due to the integration method.

I've been fighting with this for a while and appreciate any help. Thanks.

edit: corrected typo

Comment: Did you have a look at http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/ and http://code.google.com/p/sympy/

Comment: @pyfunc: I looked at them earlier. Sympy doesn't seem to like my double integral. MPMath I think uses a similar method to evaluate the integrals as scipy does, so it is currently taking quite a while  with the above p vector consisting of only three distributions.

Comment: I don't see anywhere a definition of psi1 and psi2, and unless psi2 is always smaller than psi1, there is no guarantee that the weight distC.cdf(psi1)-distC.cdf(psi2) is not negative. I don't understand the algorithm, shouldn't there be as many integrals as the dimension of your random variable vector (larger than 2). If it gets too messy, I would switch to Monte Carlo integration.

Comment: @user333700: Sorry for the confusion. In my code, x and y are psi1 and psi2, but I switched them when posting. I have edited it correctly. As for the value of y being less than x, the limits of integration in dblquad(...) set that: x E [0,1] and y E [0,x]. dblquad is supposed to do the double integration.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to increase the speed of your computation.

1. You can use the `epsabs` and `epsrel` parameters to `dblquad` to increase the tolreance of your integration.  Of course, your results will be less accurate, but for debugging this is fine.
2. You can considerably reduce the number of function evaluations in `integrand` by reordering the code like (warning, untested code)

   ```
   def integrand(x, y):
       marg = 0.0
       cdf = dict((id(distC), distC.cdf(x) - distC.cdf(y)) for distC in p)
       for distA in p:
           weight = numpy.prod(cdf[id(distC)]
                               for distC in p if distC is not distA)
           marg += weight * distA.pdf(x) * sum(
               distB.pdf(y) for distB in p if distB is not distA)
       return (x-y) * marg
   ```

   But note that Python has quite an overhead for function calls, so writing this in pure Python won't get you too far (using something like [Cython](http://cython.org/) for this problem might help a bit).

I do not know why the integral becomes negative.  Maybe I could tell you if you would give an example for `p` -- this would enable us to actually try your code.

Answer (score 0):

The error given by the integration method is just a number telling you how well the convergence behaviour is. Have you tried to calculate explicit values of the integrand?

By the way: Are you integrating pdf's? If yes: Are you sure about your integration limits?

Comment: @user485185: Yes, the integrand contains pdfs. In words, it is (X - Y) * P(X - Y). P(X - Y) is the probability of calculating x - y and is as follows: For a given pair of distributions, weight the probability of that distribution giving you the value x or y (depending on which variable you are looking at at that moment; evaluates as P_i(x)) with the probability that it is the min or max of the set of distributions (or else you wouldn't be calculating the maximal distance using that particular distribution; evaluates as CDF_i(x) - CDF_i(y)). This I integrate over x=[0,1] and y=[0,x].